# Transparent background of ImageView goes black after going to settings fragment

Tags: android, android-layout, kotlin, graphics, imageview

I have an ImageView with a transparent background. Every time I go to the settings screen of my app, that background will turn black. Once I remove the app from the recent apps list, the background of the View turns transparent again.

The View is included in my layouts like this:

```
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp" app:srcCompat="@drawable/soul"
        android:id="@+id/soul" tools:ignore="ContentDescription"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp" android:translationZ="7dp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp" app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent" app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.45"/>
```

The settings fragment looks like this:

```
class SettingsFragment : PreferenceFragmentCompat() {
override fun onCreatePreferences(savedInstanceState: Bundle?, rootKey: String?) {
    setPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.settings, rootKey)
}
}
```

settings.xml just has some ListPreferences like this:

```
<androidx.preference.PreferenceScreen
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    app:key="rootkey">
    <ListPreference
        app:key="levellength"
        app:title="@string/setlevellength"
        app:summary="@string/setlevellengthdescription"
        app:defaultValue="42"
        app:entries="@array/levellengthkey"
        app:entryValues="@array/levellength"/>
</androidx.preference.PreferenceScreen>
```

I have only one Activity. The settings are included in onResume like this:         `val sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this)`

For those who are interested: The View is right below this text. It is a mix of white and transparent, so unless you have a dark background, you have to drag it around to see it.
[image: The View. Drag it.]

Comment: You should share your layout and how are you applying `constraintLayout` changes.

Comment: please share your layout not getting anything from this

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer myself by just setting the background for the imageview in the xml rather than just taking it from the png.

```
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="60dp" android:background="@drawable/soul"
    android:layout_height="60dp" app:srcCompat="@drawable/soul"
    android:id="@+id/soul" tools:ignore="ContentDescription"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp" android:translationZ="7dp"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp" app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent" app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.45"/>
```